# OS X Traceroute Command: what is '*'

Tags: macos, terminal

Using the `traceroute` command in  OS X 10.9.x, multiple '*' characters are printed as output. Can anyone explain exactly what these are and what they mean?

Command output example:

```
traceroute to www.google.com (xxx.xxx.xx.xxx), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  *
```

Comment: See [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/334029/what-does-mean-when-traceroute)  at ServerFault for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means traceroute didn't get any responses to its probes. The way it works is that it sends out test packets set to expire after 1 hop, two hops, etc; then it listens for "sorry, but your packet expired before I could deliver it" and prints the addresses of the routers that sent those responses. The "*"s mean it didn't hear back.

You're getting all "*"s, which means that either there's no route to the destination, or there's a firewall blocking the probes and/or the responses, or something along those lines.